# How to suppress ordering in ActiveMQ?

Tags: java, asynchronous, activemq-classic, message-queue

I have messaging queue with one producer and one consumer for asynchronous requests with guaranteed delivery with applying some timeout policy.  Ordering of these messages doesn't make sense. Every message is isolated from each other and have it's own business scenario. So I don't need any ordering in messaging queue. But the problem is that queue is blocked by first message that can't be delivered. Other messages are correct and ready to be processed in right way, but they have to wait "bad" message to be delivered.

Java and JMS with Spring on the queue client sides.

Is it possible to make ActiveMQ queue without any ordering but with individual redelivering timeouts for every message?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to solve this would be to use a Queue per message type or some other similarly logic partitioning of messages across a set of Queues.

A JMS Queue functions exactly as the name implies, first in first out.  There is one option of using message priority to allow messages to jump the line but there are many limitations for that depending on Queue depth etc.

You are far better off breaking apart you domain into some logical set of Queues and consuming for each.

Comment: Yes, I thought about logic one message - one queue, but it looks to "hacky" (sorry, can't invent more suitable word in English). How does ActiveMQ behave when amount of queues is thousands? It seems I need logic for deleting old queues or for managing several thousand pool of queues and for dispatching messages into this pool. 
In other words it's possible workaround but it is more complicated that it should be.

Comment: And I tried to play with priorities - ActiveMQ do nothing with new message with higher priority if old one wasn't delivered yet.

Comment: Read the documentation, there's answers in there for both of those questions

Answer (score 0):

Are you in a "FIFO" scenario?, ie processing order must be preserved? If not, start multiple consumers (eg multiple MDB instances, in WebSphere you set the number of "slaves" per server on the Activation Specification) on the queue and/or assign different JMSpriority to your message to process "more urgent" messages first

Comment: No, as I said in question I don't need ordering at all, so no FIFO. And I have only producer and only consumer - it's my own mini integration bus.
I tried to play with priority, but it's two problems:

1. All my messages are equal in priority. And only way to use priority - decrease it each time when message wasn't delivered.

2. It doesn't work. If some message is taken into delivery process no new messages despite priority would be processed until first one goes out of the queue.